# Batch copy files from subdirectories to a new folder?

Tags: bash, for-loop, cp

I would like to batch copy specific files that ends with fastq.gz from each folder (with unique names) to a new directory, but it keeps giving me an error saying that the files cannot be found. Is it because I am using a wildcard wrong?

```
for f in ./*/split-adapter-quality-trimmed/*.fastq.gz; do
    cp *fastq.gz ../../new;
done
```

Comment: yes, you should use `$f` instead. like `cp "$f" ../../new`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Executing `for f in ./*/split-adapter-quality-trimmed/*.fastq.gz` will already contain the filenames ending with `*.fastq.gz` in variable `f`. So use it directly in `cp` (`cp $f destination`) inside the loop. If you put an `echo $f` inside the loop, you can see all the files and verify it before `cp`.

```
for f in ./*/split-adapter-quality-trimmed/*.fastq.gz; do
    cp $f ../../new;
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Except if you absolutely want to use a `for-loop`, you could perform that with one `find` command:

```
find ./*/split-adapter-quality-trimmed -name "*fastq.gz" -exec cp {} ../../new \;
```

It will browse the directories matching `./*/split-adapter-quality-trimmed`, looking for each file terminating with `fastq.gz`, and then execute the needed cp command (in the current directory of the shell, the command line ends with a semi-colon):

```
cp <found-path> ../../new
```

(The wildcarded term `*fastq.gz` is surrounded by quotes to prevent Bash to interpret it, just in case. So is it with the semi-colon.)